# Spring util:properties - can you change the encoding to UTF-8?

Tags: spring, utf-8, properties

I'm working on converting some properties files from iso-8859-1 to utf-8. I implemented a resource.control for most resource files so that it would read as utf-8 encoding.

I came across a properties file that was defined in spring using the util:properties tag.

I was wondering if there is a way to specify that the default encoding be utf-8? I did look at the possibility defining this as a bean with the ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, however that would require a big refactoring process, since the logic in the bean expects this to be as a map.

defined using spring 3.0.5

```
<util:properties id="fooProperties" location="file:${AXE_APPCONFIG}/foo.properties"/>
```

I know that by definition java properties files are iso-8859-1 encoded, however I thought that spring might have come up with a way to change the encoding of it (like the Resource.Control)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have recently solved the same problem by using **PropertiesFactoryBean**. It is a subclass of [PropertiesLoaderSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html), which has a public setter method for you to specify encoding of your property file.

```
<beans:bean id="nameOfYourPropsVar" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:${yourPropFileName}"/>
    <beans:property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Please note that according to [the api doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html#setFileEncoding%28java.lang.String%29), it only applies to classic properties file, not to XML files.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that this is not possible. Spring will always (as of v3.0.5) use the default encoding of properties files, which is ISO-8859-1.

The alternative is to use a properties object then convert that to a map.

```
Properties propsToLoad = new Properties();
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("filename.properties");
propsToLoad.load(new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8));
```

then to convert to map

```
Map<String,String> mapYouWant = new HashMap<String,String>((Map) propsToLoad);
```